# remove ',' from ip list

Tags: bash, awk, sed

**intput**:

iprange1,  iprange2

iprange3

iprange4

**output**:

iprange1

iprange2

iprange3

iprange4

I have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/,[[:space:]]*/\n/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

replaces ", " with 2 empty rows.

```
awk '{sub(/, /,"\n\n")}1' file
```